# Is it possible to pass associative array as parameter to switch case in Php?

Tags: php

We need a control structure like switch case accepting associative array as parameter or something like bellow :

php code:

```
$asso_array = array($key => $value);

switch ($asso_array) {
    case $asso_array[$key]:
        if ($asso_array[$value] == 'something') {
            echo'then do this';
        }
}
```

Comment: No. Nor does it make much sense.

Comment: if you want multiple data to be processed why not use arrays?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `foreach`, since $key in array will have multiple values:

```
foreach($array as $key => $value){
    switch($value){
        case 'something':
              echo 'then do this';
              break;
        default:
              echo 'else do something else';
    }
}
```

Comment: @Zorba You can't use array in switch. http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php SWITCH == MULTI-LEVEL IF

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use a function:

```
<?php



function myFunction ($key,  $value){
    switch ($key) {
        case 'a':
            // do something with value
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

$array = array();
foreach($array as $key => $value){
    myFunction($key, $value);
}
```

Comment: As far as I know, not possible in php

Answer (score 0):

Loop through array elements and switch on 'key':

```
foreach($asso_array as $key => $value){
  switch($key)
  {
    case 'something': 
                      if($value === 'something')
                      {
                        echo "then do this";
                      }
                      //You can even do a nested switch on $value here.
                      break;
             default: break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Updated my answer. `$value` is visible inside the switch. So you can use a if or switch on `$value` inside a `case`. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think below code can help you better - -

```
$alpha = array("a" => "apple", "b" => "banana", "c" => "cat", "d" => "dog");

function print_alpha($arr_alpha, $key, $input) {
    if($key == $input) {
        switch($key) {
            case 'a':
                echo '"a" for Apple';
            break;
            case 'b':
                echo '"b" for Banana';
            break;
            case 'c':
                echo '"c" for Cat';
            break;
            default:
                echo "'$input' still has to be involved in a case";
        }
    }
}
// Now call the function for each key
array_walk($alpha, 'print_alpha', 'a');
array_walk($alpha, 'print_alpha', 'd');
```

You can extend it more logically.

Answer (score -1):

Well thanks guys i solved this problem by using following structure of array :

```
 $asso_array = array('key1'=>array('a'=>'b'),'key2'=>array('c'=>'d'));

 foreach ( $asso_array as $key =>$val){
   switch($key)
    {
       case 'key1':

          if($asso_array['key1']['a'] == 'something')
            {
               echo $asso_array['key1']['a'];
            }

      case 'key2':

      if($asso_array['key2']['c'] == 'something')
        {
           echo $asso_array['key2']['c'];
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: The `switch` makes absolutely no sense here. None. Whatsoever.

Comment: You know that `switch ($a) case $b: ...` is the same as `if ($a == $b)`? Your `switch` is still entirely superfluous.